# What is the shortcut key to rotate photos in Photos app

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts, photos

How to rotate photos in Photos app using shortcut keys?  I have found that <kbd>+</kbd>  <kbd>-</kbd>will zoom in and out the picture and <kbd>*</kbd> will fit the image to the original size. And also I found that the rotating direction can be changed by clicking the rotate button on below left corner with pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. But I need a shortcut key that can easily rotate the image by pressing one or two keys maximum. Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> but it only rotates the image right, so you need to press the key 3 times to rotate it to the left. <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> does the same thing. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> also rotates the image to the right. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> doesn't work.